# android:use static variables

Tags: android

when pressing home button application is minimized and wait an hour and reopen the application the static variables before assigning values are null why happends anyone give me answer Thanks in advance.

Comment: The OS can kill your app whenever it wants (needs the memory) therefore your variables can be null.

Comment: use shared preference.

Comment: how can i save an arraylist of object in sharedPreferences?

Comment: Yo can not save objects to sharedPreferences. only primitive datatypes and Strings are allowed to store in shared preferences. SharedPrefernces internally created an XML file of key value pair. so no object can be stored in sharedpreferences.

Comment: Kalpesh . You can also store object in shared prefrences, To store object first serialize it then store and when retrieving deserialize it and use it

Answer (score 0):

Static variable also gets garbage collected once there is no instance of the class is in class loader sub system So you can not persist data in static variable . If you want to persist data then You can use shared preferences  .

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your variable state through `onSaveInstanceState()` function or using `SharedPreference` instead.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
}
```